# Limit Selected Options in Laravel

Tags: laravel, synchronization, laravel-blade

I'm using **sync** method in my Laravel app for related tables ex: `post` `tags` `post_tags` now I want to limit user tags selection up to `3` ***meaning*** user is not allowed to select more than 3 tags. How can I do that?

**Blade**

```
{{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags') }}
{{ Form::select('tags[]', $tags2, null, 
    ['class' => 'chosen-select', 'multiple' => 'multiple'])}}
```

**Controller->edit()**

```
public function edit()
{
    $tags = Tag::orderby('title', 'desc')->get();
    $tags2 = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->title;
    }
}
```

**Controller->update()**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
   $post->save();
   $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery on your front end and limit the users selections.

Using `change` event you can do something like this:

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```